# Nested Collection View in Table View throws error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have collection view in a table view (Nested collection views) and I dont know why everytime I scroll my table I catch this error:

> The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>
> the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>
> The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is:
>
> < UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 
>   0x7ff85d0622c0>, and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {-120, 0}; contentSize: {255, 150.5}> collection view layout: .
>       2017-05-17 12:02:48.637 FAM[19475:2158765] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

[image: My SB]

Comment: its saying uicollectionviewcell height should not exceed uicollectionview+inset. try this to correct

Comment: @Omnia adjust your collection view scroll view insets from storyboard.

Comment: use this `-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return self.collectionView.frame.size;
}`